elastic beanstalk create-environment:: when calling the CreateEnvironment operation: Configuration validation exception
An error occurred (ConfigurationValidationException) when calling the CreateEnvironment operation: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchtemplate', OptionName: 'LaunchTemplateId'): Unknown configuration setting.
I am trying to create the elasticbeanstalk with launch template

aws elasticbeanstalk create-application 
--application-name my-first-webapp-beanstalk 
--description "My first Elastic Beanstalk web application"

aws ec2 create-launch-template 
--launch-template-name MyElasticBeanstalkLaunchTemplate 
--version-description "Version 1" 
--launch-template-data '{
"IamInstanceProfile": {
"Arn": "arn:aws:iam::********:instance-profile/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
},
"InstanceType": "t3.micro",
"SecurityGroupIds": ["sg-1234567"],
"KeyName": "varunkm",
"ImageId": "ami-2348283462938"
}'

Creating the environment :


aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment 
--region eu-north-1 
--application-name My-first-webapp-beanstalk 
--environment-name My-first-webapp-beanstalk-env 
--solution-stack-name "64bit Amazon Linux 2023 v6.2.2 running Node.js 20" 
--option-settings 
Namespace=aws:autoscaling:launchtemplate,OptionName=LaunchTemplateId,Value=lt-1232365427345875324 
Namespace=aws:ec2:instances,OptionName=InstanceTypes,Value=t3.micro 
Namespace=aws:ec2:instances,OptionName=SecurityGroups,Value=sg-1234567
Getting an error
An error occurred (ConfigurationValidationException) when calling the CreateEnvironment operation: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchtemplate', OptionName: 'LaunchTemplateId'): Unknown configuration setting.
